# What is the correct HDR mapping with blender internal (native) render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I downloaded HDR image from https://hdri-skies.com. And added it to world texture. There seems to be some problem in maping.

What is the correct HDR mapping with blender internal (native) render?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in the maping.

**Equirectangular** is the correct mapping method.

Problem was in **World**

In properties>World **Paper Sky** was checked and i had to un check this

Note: I also unchecked **Blend Sky** as it was giving a dull sublte lighting.

[image]
[image]